# PreferenceActivity error: doesn't show selected option after close Activity

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences, preferenceactivity

The value is saved well in SharedPreference when i push it , but it doesn't show when i open another time the PreferenceActivity. **It runs if i don't put the `android:entryValues`** , but i can't use it  cause there is some difference using distinct languages in order to see what's the value of the prefference.

¿Any idea of what can i do?

Thanks for reading.

code:

the PreferencesMenu **activity**:

```
public class PreferencesMenu extends PreferenceActivity  
{
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setDefaultKeyMode(MODE_PRIVATE);

     addPreferencesFromResource(R.layout.preferences);
     getPreferenceManager().setSharedPreferencesName("Gat_Preferences");

 }
}
```

some of **strings.xml**:

```
    <string-array name="menu_preference_general_order_array">
        <item>Default</item>
        <item>Alphabetical</item>
    </string-array>     
    <string-array name="menu_preference_general_order_values">
        <item>default</item>
        <item>alphabetical</item>
    </string-array>
```

preferences.xml **layout**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
     ...
<PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/menu_preference_general">
    <ListPreference 
        android:key="list_order"
        android:persistent="true"
        android:title="@string/menu_preference_general_order_title"
        android:summary="@string/menu_preference_general_order_description"
        android:entries="@array/menu_preference_general_order_array"
        android:entryValues="@array/menu_preference_general_order_values"/> 
    </PreferenceCategory>  
</PreferenceScreen>
```

**mod** :

I use android 2.1 , and i can't use the new fragments preference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell the preference API what file name you want to use *before* loading everything up.

Instead of this:

```
 addPreferencesFromResource(R.layout.preferences);
 getPreferenceManager().setSharedPreferencesName("Gat_Preferences");
```

Do this:

```
 getPreferenceManager().setSharedPreferencesName("Gat_Preferences");
 addPreferencesFromResource(R.layout.preferences);
```

On a sidenote, don't use `R.layout.preferences`. You should use `R.xml.preferences`, putting the file under `/res/xml` and not under `/res/layout`. It does work your way, but it's not guaranteed to work in all API versions, since it's not the default way of working with preferences XML files.

Comment: On a side-side note, I wouldn't mess with file names. Unless you have a reason to, and I tell you I've never had, it's better to just call PreferenceManager to get the defaultSharedPreferences and let the API work with that. You abstract the file names between your different classes, thus avoiding a potential source of bugs (misspelling etc.). And about your layout vs xml issue, I tested here on 1.5 and it works. But I still recommend you to put it in the right place.

Comment: Thanks for your fantastic answer (it runs perfect) . I would try what you say about not use labels for preferences , and i didn't know about R.xml.preferences , but thanks anyway . Where have you seen that things? API maybe? a book?

Answer (score 0):

Your `preferences.xml` should be in `res/xml`.
Also, you should assign the default value

```
<ListPreference 
    android:key="list_order"
    android:persistent="true"
    android:title="@string/menu_preference_general_order_title"
    android:summary="@string/menu_preference_general_order_description"
    android:entries="@array/menu_preference_general_order_array"
    android:entryValues="@array/menu_preference_general_order_values"
    android:defaultValue="default"
    />
```

Comment: Once again, like I had said before, neither is the problem. First, you do *not* need to put the prefs XML file under /res/xml. It *loads* just fine from /res/layout. Of course, that's not a good practice, and it's possible that it will break somewhere, sometime. However, for his limited example and problem, it works fine on layout, since the add command load the XML itself, and expects a valid XML file as long as you provide the correct path (R.layout). Placing in the proper place is a *good practice*, not his *solution*.

Comment: About the default value, it still does not solve his problem. By just providing a default value, you replace his original problem --- blank selector everytime he restarts the app --- with another problem: always the provided default value everytime he restarts the app. To see how it fails, just select the "Alphabetical" option using your solution. Next time, the app will show "default". The reason behind that I explained in my answer: when you provide this default value, that default value is written to the default prefs file (packagename_preferences.xml under /data/data/packagename).

Comment: When he add the preferences before setting his custom pref file name, the preferences are loaded from the default. However, when he sets the pref file to that custom, all user changes are written to that custom prefs file, thus the user always see the default value in the default prefs file, but always end up setting the values to the custom prefs file. As I said, the solution is inverting the calls to the custom prefs file and where he adds the preferences from a resource.