# How to bind the automatic preferences file to the custom preferences in android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, preferenceactivity, listpreference

I just implemented a preferences screen for one of the sample apps that I am creating. I followed the guide given on google site. All is fine and I loaded up a ListPreference and I am able to store it and persist it also. There is also one minor problem here. I have already defined a custom preference file for the app but this automatic handling of the preference screeen seems to be creating a preference file on its own. For now I was trying to get this code to work but it is not getting the custom preference file.

```
        final Preference customPrefs = getPreferenceScreen().findPreference(Utils.PREFS_NAME);

    customPrefs.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {

        public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
            customPrefs.getEditor().commit();
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Is there a way to bind the custom preference file with this auto preference class in anyway ?

Comment: Tell us how (code) you're implementing and binding to the custom preferences file. Besides, why don't you just use the default implementation? Unless you need different files, there's no need to have to handle that. It's just one more source of misspellings and problems...

Comment: This is how I get the instance of the custom perference file "Utils.setSpPreferences(getSharedPreferences(Utils.PREFS_NAME, 0));". I do want to use the default preferences file. But I have been testing my app in multiple devices with the custom preferences file. I do not want to change that now.

Comment: I ended replacing the custom preference with the default preference as you suggested. Saved a lot of time. Should have done that earlier. Thanks again. I voted you up but if you can post it as an answer I will accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set a custom name for the file used to store the preferences, used in your `PreferenceActivity`, by calling its `getPreferenceManager().setSharedPreferencesName("file_name")` method. Just remember that you need to set that *before* calling `addPreferencesFromResource`, otherwise your UI will still change stuff back to the wrong file (the default one).

As I said, you don't *need* to do that, since you can use the default file provided by the system. If/when you need to read the preferences elsewhere, you can then just call `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Context context)`.

I already addressed [those remarks in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8156525/489607).

Also remember that some of the methods are deprecated. If you're writing new code, try to avoid them and conform to the new "Fragment Way" of doing things.

Comment: Thanks David. I ended up using the default preference file.